# Appending data into an undeclared list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Every once in a while the following scenario turns up while I code in Python:

I iterate through a loop and find that I want to store the intermediate values of a variable in a list to be used later. Following is a very basic sample code:

```
for x in range(0,10):
    y = x*x
    temp_list.append(y)
```

The problem is `temp_list` has not been declared yet. So I usually navigate to the top of the loop and then add the following:

```
temp_list = []
for x in range(0,10):
    y = x*x
    temp_list.append(y)
```

While this may seem trivial, I was just wondering whether there is any pythonic way to create a list if it does not exist and then append a value to it, or else if it exists, just append?

Comment: You could use a try/except block to check if x is set (`try: \ x \ except NameError: \ x = []`), but that's not really very pythonic IMHO. (NOTE: I'm using '\' to indicate line breaks here)

Comment: Yes that was what I was thinking. But I was wondering the try except block would consume more time. As you can see the exception will be only on the first attempt after which we do not require it at all. If the number of iterations in the loop are very high, will the try except block add a lot of overhead?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is in python, but IIRC, in other languages, try blocks are only expensive when they throw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your very base sample it can be done using list comprehension:

```
l = [x*x for x in range(0, 10)]
```

Comment: True, but like I said this is just a sample code. Usually I would have to store an intermediate variable 'y' which is available inside a big loop. Also the value of y is obtained after a lot of data processing which we may not be able to describe in a single line. In other words, I may not be able to use list comprehension

Comment: @Pulimon: You can always use list comprehension by putting your complex piece of code into a function of (even better) a generator function.

Comment: @Ber Done, thank you - it was just an option - to show that variables can be obtained by locals

Answer (score 4):

It should be always clear if a variable is declared or not. How otherwise would you like to access it?

What you can do dynamically is a dict entry:

```
a = {}

for x in range(0,10):
    y = x*x
    a.setdefault('temp_list', []).append(y)
```

The `a['temp_list']` will be created only if needed.

Comment: Oh this is an interesting approach

Answer (score 2):

Depending in your problem, a good "pythonic" way of dealing with that sort of structure could be to abstract it into a generator.  For your trivial example:

```
def squares():
    for x in range(0,10):
        y = x*x
        yield y
```

Then:

```
temp_list = [i for i in squares()]
```

Very often when you need a temporary list like that its because you are running a series of operations on your data, each of which involves another loop.  Using generators instead can significantly improve both performance and memory usage because they result on only a single loop.

Note that for trivial examples its usually easier to write a generator expression:

```
temp_list = (x*x for x in range(0, 10))
```

If you want a not-so-pythonic way of doing it, you can edit the locals dictionary, but this is not really a good idea since it leads to obfuscated code:

```
for x in range(0, 10):
    y = x*x
    locals().setdefault('temp_list', []).append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve using locals as per OPs template,

```
for x in range(0,10):
   y = x * x
   temp_list = temp_list + [y] if "temp_list" in locals() else [y]

print(temp_list)
```

gives,

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

[Program finished]
```

but yes, this should probably be solved with list comprehension